# What is the pythonic way for 'do_this() if condition else pass '?

Tags: python, if-statement

There is exists a way for writing this in a single line?

```
>> list.append(elem) if condition else pass
```

I have needed sometimes something like that and I don't know the best way for accomplish it.

Comment: Better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: This might be on-topic for Code Review, assuming **A)** the code works, **and B)** the code isn't hypothetical or incomplete in any way

Comment: Do you only want to check for the `else` condition or also for the `if` condition?

Comment: I wrote a bad example in my question. I'm interested in writing something like do_tjhis if the condition is True else do nothing in a single line.

Comment: @Luis: Why do you want a single line? Trying to fit multiple things into a single statement is actually very ***anti-*** Pythonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if` statements are exactly meant for conditionally executing a statement!

```
if condition:
    list.append(elem)
```

If you *really* wanted it all in one line, I suppose you could do:

```
if condition: list.append(elem)
```

But this would definitely much less readable and idiomatic!

---

For your second example (update: it was edited out of the question), Python lets you use a ternary expression anywhere, so you can shorten

```
list.append(elem) if condition else other_list.append(elem)
```

into:

```
(list1 if condition else list2).append(elem)
```

However, it would be more readable—and thus, again, more idiomatic—to split the above into two statements:

```
lucky_list = list1 if condition else list2
lucky_list.append(elem)
```

Comment: I have updated the question because I wrote a bad example and the question it was confusing.

Comment: @LuisGonzález You _can_ fit it into one line, but that would be less readable and thus less idiomatic; answer updated accordingly.

Comment: I though that the one line approach it was more readable. I will have it in account since now

Answer (score 2):

```
if condition:
    list.append(elem)
else:
    other_list.append(elem)
```

There are other ways possible, but this is the most Pythonic.

Comment: I have updated the question because I wrote a bad example and the question it was confusing. Thanks

Comment: I would still recommend using an `if` statement. There's no need nor any value in trying to be compact at the expense of readability.